# Instalar QtARMSim en Lubuntu

Tags: python, linux, unix, ensamblador, pyinstaller

quiero instalar el QtARMSim en Lubuntu para practicar con ensamblador, estoy siguiendo esta pequeña guía https://www.studocu.com/es-ar/document/universidad-nacional-del-nordeste/arquitectura-y-organizacion-de-computadoras/apuntes/manual-de-instalacion-de-qtarmsim/2854323/view . El problema viene cuando ejecuto el segundo(me dice que no se pudo obtener algunos archivos) y tercer comando("Could no find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2", tengo la versión de Python 3.6.9).
¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip ruby
sudo gem install gosu
sudo pip install PySide2
sudo pip3 install QtARMSim
```

Acabo de probarlo en mi distro, y me funciono, hay algunas versiones de pyside que bloquean el funcionamiento de qtarmsim

Comment: He estado intentandolo pero por desgracia no me ha funcionado, me sigue apareciendo el mensaje "No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos", ¿puede que tenga algo mal configurado?

Comment: Que version de Lubuntu estas utilizando?

Comment: Tengo la version 18.04

Comment: Probaste cambiando el servidor de descarga? Muchas veces, cambiando el servidor se solucionan estos problemas. Estoy al tanto

Tambien intestaste actualizando los repositorios?

Comment: ¿Como hago eso? Disculpeme, soy nuevo en linux.

Comment: Primero actualiza tu distribucion.

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Luego, en origenes de software, puedes seleccionar el servidor. Aqui tienes un manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.3/software_sources.html)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! He conseguido instalarlo, el problema ahora es que al ensamblar me dice que no ha podido conectarse al servidor de Ruby

Answer (score 1):

Las instrucciones actualizadas de instalación de QtARMSim están en https://pypi.org/project/qtarmsim/. Las instrucciones que aparecen en dicha página para Ubuntu son:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip ruby
$ # See https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux
$ # for installing the gosu dependencies
$ sudo gem install gosu
$ sudo pip3 install QtARMSim
```

Supongo que el problema que comentas tiene que ver con la última orden. 
El paquete QtARMSim tiene como dependencia a PySide2, lo cual generalmente está bien ya que evita tener que instalar PySide2 de forma manual. Sin embargo, puede ocurrir que se haya publicado recientemente una nueva versión de PySide2 y aún no hayan binarios para una determinada combinación de arquitectura/sistema operativo/versión de python. (Lo que se puede comprobar en https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/#files)

Si este es el caso, una posible solución es ver si hay un paquete (o varios) de PySide2 para python3 en la distribución en la que se esté instalando QtARMSim. Si es así, se pueden instalar con el gestor de paquetes de la distribución. En Lubuntu, estos paquetes probablemente comiencen con python3-pyside2.

Una vez instalados los paquetes anteriores, simplemente hay que instalar QtARMSim ignorando sus dependencias con:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --no-deps QtARMSim
```

Y ya debería ir.